# option selected in entity field type

Tags: symfony

I have this entity, using the query builder I get a list of options to display in a select, then I want to select one of this option. I'm using 'data' to select the option with id = 1 but it doesn't work, any idea on how to select an option?
thanks

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if($options['project'] instanceof Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Project){
        $projectId = $options['project']->getId();
    }
    else{
        $projectId = null;
    }

    if($options['sprint'] instanceof Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Sprint ){
        $sprintId = $options['sprint']->getId();
    }
    else{
        $sprintId = null;
    }

    $builder
        ->add('type', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                ''          =>  '--',
                'new'       =>  'New',
                'bugfix'    =>  'Bugfix'
            )))
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('project', 'entity', array(
            'class' =>  'CpjProjectsBundle:Project',
            'property'  =>  'name',
            'empty_value' => '--',
            'empty_data'  => null,
            'required'      => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where("u.user = :id_user")
                        ->setParameter('id_user', $this->user);
                },
            'data'  => $projectId,
        ))
        ->add('sprint', 'entity', array(
            'class' =>  'CpjProjectsBundle:Sprint',
            'property'  =>  'name',
            'empty_value' => '--',
            'empty_data'  => null,
            'required'      => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where("u.user = :id_user")
                        ->setParameter('id_user', $this->user);
                },
            'data'  => $sprintId,
        ))
        ->add('importance', 'text')
        ->add('storypoints', 'text')
        ->add('description', 'textarea')
        ->add('howtoprove', 'textarea')
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'project'   => null,
        'sprint'    =>  null,
    ));
}

public function __construct ($user)
{
    $this->user          = $user;
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'story';
}
```

this is the action I'm using

```
    public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $story = new Story();

    $id_project = $request->query->get('project');
    $id_sprint = $request->query->get('sprint');

    $form = $this->createForm(new StoryType($user), $story);

    $form->getData()->getProject()->setValue($id_project);
    $form->getData()->getSprint()->setValue($id_sprint);
    $form->setData($form->getData());

    $project = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CpjProjectsBundle:Project')->findOneBy(array(
        'id'        =>  $id_project,
        'user'   =>  $user,
    ));
    $sprint = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CpjProjectsBundle:Sprint')->findOneBy(array(
        'id'        =>  $id_sprint,
        'user'   =>  $user,
    ));
    $form = $this->createForm(new StoryType($user), $story, array(
        'project' => $project,
        'sprint'    => $sprint,
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $story->setUser($user);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($story);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cpj_stories_homepage'));
    }
    return $this->render('CpjProjectsBundle:Story:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try just setting the project and the sprint on the new story entity before passing it to form create. Something like this:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $story = new Story();

    $id_project = $request->query->get('project');
    $id_sprint = $request->query->get('sprint');

    $project = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CpjProjectsBundle:Project')->findOneBy(array(
        'id'        =>  $id_project,
        'user'   =>  $user,
    ));
    $sprint = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CpjProjectsBundle:Sprint')->findOneBy(array(
        'id'        =>  $id_sprint,
        'user'   =>  $user,
    ));

    $story->setProject($project);
    $story->setSprint($sprint);

    $form = $this->createForm(new StoryType($user), $story);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $story->setUser($user);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($story);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cpj_stories_homepage'));
    }
    return $this->render('CpjProjectsBundle:Story:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Then in your form would look like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('type', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                ''          =>  '--',
                'new'       =>  'New',
                'bugfix'    =>  'Bugfix'
            )))
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('project', 'entity', array(
            'class' =>  'CpjProjectsBundle:Project',
            'property'  =>  'name',
            'empty_value' => '--',
            'empty_data'  => null,
            'required'      => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where("u.user = :id_user")
                    ->setParameter('id_user', $this->user);
            },
        ))
        ->add('sprint', 'entity', array(
            'class' =>  'CpjProjectsBundle:Sprint',
            'property'  =>  'name',
            'empty_value' => '--',
            'empty_data'  => null,
            'required'      => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where("u.user = :id_user")
                    ->setParameter('id_user', $this->user);
            }
        ))
        ->add('importance', 'text')
        ->add('storypoints', 'text')
        ->add('description', 'textarea')
        ->add('howtoprove', 'textarea')
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'CpjProjectsBundle:Story'
    ));
}
```

You can also take out all of the stuff above `$builder->add()...` in the form

Comment: no I need to select an arbitrary options, based on a parameter I'm passing in GET. Do you think it is possible to do it from the entity type or from the controller?

Comment: Not sure I'm doing right. I updated my question with the action I'm using but I got an error when I set the value here: $form->getData()->getProject()->setValue($id_project);
thanks for your help

Comment: Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object. the row is $form->getData()->getProject()->setValue($id_project);

Comment: I dont have errors but isn't selected yet. I think the problem is some issue with objects. if I try to print echo get_class($options['sprint']); I get 'Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Sprint'. but if I try var_dump($options['sprint'] instanceof Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Sprint); i get 'boolean false'

Comment: If you are setting the Project and the Sprint on the Story entity before passing it to the form creator you dont need to set it in the form itself. you can remove all of that logic.

Comment: yes now works perfectly. btw I also needed to remove 'data'  => $projectId, from buildForm. thank you so much for the precious help!

Comment: Ok i have updated my answer to reflect those changes, if it works for you then would you be so kind as to mark it as accepted.